# insert a break after a certain line (inline-block) unordered list

Tags: html, css, web

I am making a project website for HTML/CSS without the use of Javascript.
I am currently struggling with adding a break between 2 list items when the screen reaches a certain max-with. The only solution I found is adding a break between the list but I know that isn't valid.

```css
.menu br 
{
display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 859px) {
.menu br 
{
    display: inline-block;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 477px) {
.menu li
{
    display: block;
}

.menu br
{
    display: none;
}

main {
    position: static;
    margin: 10px;
}

body {
    min-width: 340px;
}
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h2>Menu</h2>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="pagina">Home</li>
    <li><a href="html/offerte.html">Aanvraag offerte</a></li>
    <li><a href="html/verhuur.html">Verhuur verhuiswagen of ladderlift</a></li>
    <br>
    <li><a href="html/stappenplan.html">Stappenplan verhuis</a></li>
    <li><a href="html/geschiedenis.html">Geschiedenis</a></li>
    <li><a href="html/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an empty `li` with `height` and show it on small screens.

```css
.menu li.hidden-sm 
{
display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 859px) {
.menu li.hidden-sm {
    list-style: none;
    height: 20px;
        display: block;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 477px) {
.menu li
{
    display: block;
}

.menu li.hidden-sm
{
    display: none;
}

main {
    position: static;
    margin: 10px;
}

body {
    min-width: 340px;
}
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h2>Menu</h2>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="pagina">Home</li>
    <li><a href="html/offerte.html">Aanvraag offerte</a></li>
    <li><a href="html/verhuur.html">Verhuur verhuiswagen of ladderlift</a></li>
    <li class="hidden-sm"></li>
    <li><a href="html/stappenplan.html">Stappenplan verhuis</a></li>
    <li><a href="html/geschiedenis.html">Geschiedenis</a></li>
    <li><a href="html/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class on the third `li` and give that class a `margin-bottom` in CSS:

### HTML:

```
<li class="test">
   <a href="html/verhuur.html">Verhuur verhuiswagen of ladderlift</a>
</li>
```

### CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 859px) {
  .test {
      margin-bottom: 1rem;       
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 477px) {
   .test {
      margin-bottom: 0;       
   }
}
```